# J2ME: Application is untrusted and maybe harmful to your phone

Tags: java-me, certificate, midp, s60

I got my R&D signed app from Java Verified submission portal.

I install it on my S40 device and it run fine.

But in my S60 device it show an warning before install: "**Application is untrusted and may be harmful to your phone.**" And it worked like an untrusted app.

I checked certificates in this phone and there are only one UTI certificate: "MIDP 2 GeoTrust CA for UTI". is there anyway to install UTI certificate on my S60 device?

This is my Jad file:

```
MIDlet-1: hello_world,/icon.png,JDialer.GameMidlet
MIDlet-Certificate-1-1: MIIEbTCCA1WgA...
MIDlet-Certificate-1-2: MIIDzjCCArag...
MIDlet-Jar-RSA-SHA1: lCFSJEHCFKe...
MIDlet-Jar-Size: 171119
MIDlet-Jar-URL: hello_world.jar
MIDlet-Name: hello_world
MIDlet-Permissions: javax.microedition.pim.ContactList.read, javax.microedition.pim.ContactList.write
MIDlet-Vendor: Vendor
MIDlet-Version: 1.4
MicroEdition-Configuration: CLDC-1.1
MicroEdition-Profile: MIDP-2.0
```

Please help me regarding this and thanks for your reading.

Comment: which s60 device you are using ?

Comment: thanks for your reply Lucifer. It is an old phones: Nokia N72 and Nokia 3250.

Comment: there must be a install certificate option in your phone.

Comment: I also got no luck with Nokia C6-01 (with "GeoTrust CA for UTI" certificate). My app is categorized to Untrusted Third Party.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sr, this is my confusion. I need to change permission to `Always Allowed` for my app on my real devices manually (new devices have option for this in first time run). I also install jad file instead jar file on remote device in RDA program from Nokia to make my app in 'Trusted Third Party'.